# Signing an array whit `eth_signTypedData_v4`

Tags: arrays, eip712

I'm signing an array whit `eth_signTypedData_v4` but when I try to `ecrecover` my signature I get the incorrect address

Here is my javascript code for signing the message:

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  method: 'net_version',
  params: [],
  jsonrpc: "2.0"
}, function (err, result) {
  const netId = result.result;
  console.log("netId", netId);
  const msgParams = JSON.stringify({types:
    {
    EIP712Domain:[
      {name:"name",type:"string"},
      {name:"version",type:"string"},
      {name:"verifyingContract",type:"address"}
    ],
    set:[
      {name:"from",type:"address"},
      {name:"to",type:"address"},
      {name:"nft",type:"address[]"},
      {name:"tokenid",type:"uint[]"}
    ]
  },
  primaryType:"set",
  domain:{name:"NFT",version:"1",verifyingContract:exchangeadddress},
  message:{
    from: "0xb71Ff4Db03DB070e40c90F5e2d40b32AAeff556b",
    to: "0x79158a488A704f6626C1AddC8b1A18A75Da3BDd1",
    nft: ["0xe46e2362b71C3C820a2170CdD95e9e1F1193cbc6","0x3bc62484E9Fe4CaB46289fb2F133367cE28E0457"],
    tokenid: ["1","2"]
  }
  })

  var from = signer;

  console.log('CLICKED, SENDING PERSONAL SIGN REQ', 'from', from, msgParams)
  var params = [from, msgParams]
  console.dir(params)
  var method = 'eth_signTypedData_v4'

  web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
    method,
    params,
    from,
  }, async function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.dir(err)
    if (result.error) {
      alert(result.error.message)
    }
    if (result.error) return console.error('ERROR', result)
    console.log('TYPED SIGNED:' + JSON.stringify(result.result))


    const signature = result.result.substring(2);
    console.log(signature)
    const r = "0x" + signature.substring(0, 64);
    const s = "0x" + signature.substring(64, 128);
    const v = parseInt(signature.substring(128, 130), 16);
    console.log("r:", r);
    console.log("s:", s);
    console.log("v:", v);
    setrA(r)
    setsA(s)
    setvA(v)


  }) 
})
```

Here is my solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.8.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";


contract fin is ReentrancyGuard {



    function Swap(
        address [] memory nft,
        address userAddressFrom, 
        address userAddressTo, 
        uint [] memory tokenId,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
   
    ) 
        external  {


        bytes32 eip712DomainHash = geteip712DomainHash ();
        bytes32 hashStruct = gethashStruct(userAddressFrom, userAddressTo, nft, tokenId);
        require (verifySignature(userAddressFrom,  eip712DomainHash,  hashStruct, v, r, s) == true,"signature of user A is invalid");

   
    }


    function geteip712DomainHash () public view  returns (bytes32) {
        return
        keccak256(
        abi.encode(
            keccak256(
                "EIP712Domain(string name,string version,address verifyingContract)"
            ),
            keccak256(bytes("NFT")),
            keccak256(bytes("1")),
            address(this)
        )
        );
    }

    function gethashStruct(address from, address to, address[] memory nft, uint[] memory tokenid)
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        return
     keccak256(
      abi.encode(
          keccak256("set(address from,address to,address[] nft,uint[] tokenid)"),
          from,
          to,
          nft,
          tokenid
        )
        
    );
    }
 
    function verifySignature (address _user, bytes32 eip712DomainHash, bytes32 hashStruct, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
        public
        pure returns (bool) { 
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", eip712DomainHash, hashStruct));
         return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s) == _user;
        }

   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to abi encodePacked the array values in the `getHashStruct()`.

OpenSea Seaport example: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport/blob/a62c2f8f484784735025d7b03ccb37865bc39e5a/reference/lib/ReferenceGettersAndDerivers.sol#L130

From https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-712.md#definition-of-encodedata:

`The array values are encoded as the keccak256 hash of the concatenated encodeData of their contents (i.e. the encoding of SomeType[5] is identical to that of a struct containing five members of type SomeType).`

```
  function getHashStruct(
        address from,
        address to,
        address[] memory nft,
        uint256[] memory tokenid
    ) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return
            keccak256(
                abi.encode(
                    keccak256('set(address from,address to,address[] nft,uint[] tokenid)'),
                    from,
                    to,
                    keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nft)),
                    keccak256(abi.encodePacked(tokenid))
                )
            );
    }
```

Comment: Spent a couple of hours double-checking my code, turns out I needed to encode/hash the array values just like that. Thanks!